# Is it good practice to pass arguments to Docker containers through environment variables?

Tags: python, docker

I have an image whose task is to run a simulation. However there are some settings that I want to change in different simulations.

To achieve this, I set some environment variables when starting a container, which then I pass as command line arguments to my main simulation script.

Is this considered good practice for creating "customized" containers from the same image?

Comment: you can pass environment variables in the command line.

Comment: Yes it is. And if there are too many of them use a config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical ways to configure a container include:

- command line arguments (often paired with an entrypoint)
- environment variables
- config file mounted as a volume or docker config

There's no one best way, though the config file method is typically used for passing a larger amount of configuration into a container that may also be checked into version control. Environment variables are perfectly acceptable and are also described in the [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/) design.